# Google analytics generalized mail.foo.tld regex filter?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to write a google analytics regex that will take all the sources of xxxxx.xxxxx.xxx.mail.foo.tld and rewrite it to mail.foo.tld

Currently I have the main two setup - mail.live.com and mail.yahoo.com.

```
Field A -> Extract A -- Campaign source -- .*\.mail\.yahoo\.com$
Output To -> Constructor -- Campaign source -- mail.yahoo.com
```

But, I have half a dozen other xxxx.xxxxx.mail.foo.tld that I would like to rewrite.

This is what I have so far:

```
Field A -> Extract A -- Campaign source -- .*\.mail\.(\w+)\.(\w+).*$
Output To -> Constructor -- Campaign source -- mail.$A1.$A2
```

I'm hoping to have $A1 be the domain name and $A2 be the domain (.com, .net, .co.uk, etc).

I'm particulary concerned that .co.uk and similar don't turn into garbage because once they're garbage I have no way to go back and edit the GA records.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't forget a character class such as `w` needs escaping so it should actually be `\w`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what patterns you are trying to match this could work:

```
Field A -> Extract A -- Campaign source -- .+\.mail\.([\w\.]+)$
Output To -> Constructor -- Campaign source -- mail.$A1
```

This would mean:

```
.+\.        - this bit requires some kind of subdomain before mail
mail\.      - this requires a mail. subdomain in there
([\w\.]+)$  - this requires something to be after the mail. and captures the 
              whole lot into a single capture group. It doesn't matter if 
              this is a .com .co.uk etc
```

When I say "Depending on what patterns" what I'm thinking is - is there anything that would get in the way of a match by clamping the end ($) in this manner. If there are querystrings etc tagged on the end then this could have problems and you should use a different technique (If you could post some example strings you need to match it would help)

In fact if that is the case you could just make the second tld optional:

```
Field A -> Extract A -- Campaign source -- .+\.mail\.([\w]+(\.[\w]+)?)$
Output To -> Constructor -- Campaign source -- mail.$A1
```

In this case it is saying the same as before but the `(\.[\w]+)?` means an optional second .tld

Comment: This is great, thank you for the help. To my understanding, GA already truncates the URL... so the $ clamp should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this one: it puts the criteria to the end of the domain string, having a tld from 2 to 4 chars, and handles any number of sub domain levels:

```
(messag|courrier|zimbra|imp|mail)(.*)\.(.*)\..{2,4}$
```

You can customize the list of services you want to catch, in addition to the ones mentioned here, depending on ISPs present in your area.